# Wordpress Functions - adding plugins to new taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I've got a wordpress site, and in the dashboard, I've added a new menu item - Property, which has a list of meta fields such as location, price etc.

But also to this, I want to add the Attachments plugin to it, so every new single property will be able to add an attachment for an image gallery I have set up. How do I do this?

As more info for this, I've defined this in my functions.php:

```
$property->add_meta_box( 
    'Property Info', 
    array(
        array(
            'name'          => 'price',
            'label'         => 'Price',
            'description'   => 'Leave Blank for TBC',
            'type'          => 'text'
        ),
        array(
              'name'        => 'bedrooms',
              'label'       => 'Bedrooms',
              'type'        => 'text'
        ),
        array(
              'name'        => 'location',
              'label'       => 'Location',
              'type'        => 'select',
              'options'     => get_array_of_locations(),
        ),
        array(
              'name'        => 'property_type',
              'label'       => 'Type',
              'type'        => 'select',
              'options'     => get_array_of_property_types(),
        ),
        array(
              'name'        => 'postcode',
              'label'       => 'Postcode',
              'type'        => 'text',
        ),
    )
);
```

But I can't figure out how to add http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/attachments/installation/ to my new $property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put

```
define( 'ATTACHMENTS_LEGACY', true ); // force the legacy version of Attachments
```

at the top of the config file instead of the bottom, and it worked.